# Find a continuous map of the open interval

Tags: real-analysis

Find a continuous map of the open interval $(0, 1)\subset{R}$ to itself which has no
fixed point in $(0, 1)$.

I have been told to find a map $R\to{R}$ of the
form $(x)$ $=$ $x\over{2}$ $+$ $c$ which sends the open interval $(0, 1)$ into itself and which
has $x = 1$ as its unique fixed point

Comment: You have been given a good hint except that the equal sign should be an arrow.  Now for a fixed point the left and right sides of the arrow are equal.  What does that tell you about $c$?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the "picture proof" of Brouwer's fixed point theorem in one dimension, you can guess this quite easily. Draw the unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and the diagonal, the graph of $y=x$. The graph of any continuous function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is a continuous "curve" starting at $x=0$, with $y$-value staying between $0$ and $1$, and ending at $x=1$. It's pretty easy to see that you need to cross $y=x$ at some point, or meet it at one of the two endpoints.

Find a function that only meets the graph of $y=x$ at one of $x=0$ or $x=1$; when you restrict to $(0,1)$, you will have the desired function with no fixed points in $(0,1)$. (For example, many functions of the form $x^\alpha$.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try $c = 1/2$ if you want the solution suggested by the hint you gave.